# picklist value filters in list view showing all values despite record type

Tags: picklist, record-type, list-view

I have set a support process with different values for a picklist field based on record type.
RT x shows only values 'a', 'b' and 'c' for field__c and RT y shows only values 'aa', 'bb' and 'cc' for the same field__c.

I have noticed that when I create a new list view and add a filter on that field__c, and I am logged in as a user that has RT x set as default,  the little lens showing all available values for that picklist fields shows 'a', 'aa', 'b', 'bb', 'c', 'cc' but I should be viewing only 'a', 'b' and 'c'.

For example, in this screenshot I should not see value 'A&C'.
[image: For example, in this screenshot I should not see value 'A&C'.]

Do you have any idea on why this happen? Is there some configuration I am missing?

Thanks

Comment: can you provide a screenshot?

Comment: I believe this is working per design, since we experience this as well.  Since you're not actually creating a record when generating a list view, there's nothing controlling what picklist items are available in the list-view filter.  Similar issue when filtering reports.   Looking forward to anyone else posting otherwise.

Comment: screenshot added

Comment: Record type restrictions are only applicable for record creation.  List view filters are not controlled in the same way.

Comment: The record type restriction is only applicable while creating a record. It is possible that the user who does not have access to RT y can still be made owner of a record with RT y. In that case, the user will be able to access and edit that record, the picklist values would be available to the user as per RT y. Therefore it is possible for your user to have access to records of both the record types and so the list views are expected to show all the values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is working as design. Record types are not used to restrict visibility of any record unlike OWD.

Lets take this example :
UserA has access to record type A, and UserB has access to record type B. If UserB wants to see all record of type A and if option is not available in ListView and Report, how he will see those records created by UserA?

So, I would says this is intention of this feature.